# Want get a report for all pipeline with who initiated it, who approved it and who deployed it

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Need a generate a repo for all pipeline with who initiated it, who approved it and who deployed it.

Can you please help me how to generate a report for pipeline with requirements details ?

Require the report with requirement details

Comment: May i know what kind is your pipeline? Yaml or Classic editor one? Build or Release? Pipeline doesn't have approval by default, it seems not make sense to get the report for `all pipeline`, do you want to get the info for specific pipeline? And what kind of approval in your pipeline?

Comment: I need the report for both pipelines (YAML and Classic). In the release pipeline, we have approval in gate for all pipeline of production environment, thus I want the report who did the approval for the pipeline.

Comment: Please click into the release run(or pipeline run), on the `History` tab, it contains the info who created it, approved it and deployed it, may i know if the info meets your requirements?

Comment: There, i can see and get the details of who operated the pipeline only not approved, we are looking the solution to get a report of approved the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

> In the release pipeline, we have approval in gate for all pipeline of production environment, thus I want the report who did the approval for the pipeline.

This is **no** official rest api to get the info you required, but you can get related info on the `History` tab. sample as below:

[image]

You can press `F12` on browser to check the `network trace` to get the related rest api.

[image]

I have `one` stage with `pre-deployment approval` required on my release, to get the info required with below script:

```
# Set your Azure DevOps organization and project details
$organizationName = "orgname"
$projectName = "projectname"
$releaseId = "14"  # Replace with the actual pipeline ID

# Personal Access Token (PAT) for authentication
$pat = "PAT"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $User,$pat)))
$header = @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo); "accept"="application/json;api-version=7.2-preview.8"}


$Url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$organizationName/$projectName/_apis/Release/releases/$releaseId" + "?approvalFilters=7&propertyFilters=DownloadBuildArtifactsUsingTask%2C%20ReleaseCreationSource"

$content = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url  -Headers $header

$creatordisplayname = $content.createdBy.displayName
$creatoremail = $content.createdBy.uniqueName


$approvordisplayname = $content.environments[0].preDeployApprovals[0].approvedBy.displayName
$approvoremail = $content.environments[0].preDeployApprovals[0].approvedBy.uniqueName
$approvalType = $content.environments[0].preDeployApprovals[0].approvalType
$approvalstatus = $content.environments[0].preDeployApprovals[0].status


$deployby = $content.environments[0].deploySteps[0].requestedBy.uniqueName

echo "=======createby ========="

echo "created by: $creatordisplayname, email: $creatoremail"

echo "=======approveby ========="

echo "approvor displayname: $approvordisplayname"
echo "approvor email: $approvoremail"
echo "approval Type: $approvalType"
echo "approval tatus: $approvalstatus"

echo "=======deployby ========="

echo "deployed by: $deployby"
```

The execution result, it get the info correctly.

[image]

It could happen that you have several stages, and different approvals on each stage, or Mutiple approvers on one stage. You could need adjust the PowerShell script to your real release.